# Why a variable is undefined in this circumstance?

Tags: jquery, undefined

I have a menu, which browses through a list of slide on a specific page. It all went well with the following code (HTML):

```
<ul class="dropdown">
      <li class="orange"><a href="#" data-jumpslide="2"><div class="list-item one-liner"><div class="left"><span id="functionality-icon"></span></div> <div class="right">When to do it</div><div class="clear"></div></div></a></li>
      <li class="orange"><a href="#" data-jumpslide="3" ><div class="list-item one-liner"><div class="left"><span id="functionality-icon"></span></div> <div class="right">Key faces</div><div class="clear"></div></div></a></li>
      <li class="orange"><a href="#" data-jumpslide="5" ><div class="list-item one-liner"><div class="left"><span id="functionality-icon"></span></div> <div class="right">Functionalities</div><div class="clear"></div></div></a></li>
</ul>
```

and the jQuery is:

```
$('a[data-jumpslide]').each(function(idx, ele){
    $(ele).on('click', function(){
        var slideToJump = $(this).data('jumpslide');
        window.slider.go(false, slideToJump+1);
    });
});
```

As you can see, whenever the link is clicked, it just moved the slide on that specific page.

But now I had to create a universal menu, which could move the slider on any page. So if I am the page "Page 1" and I click a link for a 7th slide at "Page 2", the code should open the Page 2 and move to the slide 7.

This is how I changed the HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
      <li class="orange"><a href="page2.php" data-jumpslide="2" data-goto="page2"><div class="list-item one-liner"><div class="left"><span id="functionality-icon"></span></div> <div class="right">When to do it</div><div class="clear"></div></div></a></li>
      <li class="orange"><a href="page2.php" data-jumpslide="2" data-goto="page2" ><div class="list-item one-liner"><div class="left"><span id="functionality-icon"></span></div> <div class="right">Key faces</div><div class="clear"></div></div></a></li>
      <li class="orange"><a href="page2.php" data-jumpslide="2" data-goto="page2" ><div class="list-item one-liner"><div class="left"><span id="functionality-icon"></span></div> <div class="right">Functionalities</div><div class="clear"></div></div></a></li>
</ul>
```

and this is how I changed the jQuery:

```
$('a[data-jumpslide]').each(function(idx, ele){
    $(ele).on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var slideToJump = $(this).data('jumpslide');
        var gotoPage = $(this).data('data-goto');

        slideToJump++;
        if (gotoPage != '') {
              window.slider.go(false, slideToJump);
        }   
        else {
            var url = href+'#'+slideToJump;
            window.location = url;
        }
    });
});

var hash = window.location.hash;
$(document).ready(function(idx, ele){
  if (hash != '') {        
        window.setTimeout(function () {
          window.slider.go(false, hash);
        }, 2000);
    }
    else {
        console.log("No hash found  " + hash);
    }
});
```

So what happening here is that when a user clicks on any link that takes it to another page (say Page 2), it redirects and after it reaches there, it checks whether the pages has hash or not. If it does, it moves the slide to that number.

Now all is good here except the slide doesn't move to the number! Even though the code is same, even though `window.slider` is getting the slider in it, yet it still doesn't move.

When I created a console.log on the Slide Change Callback function, it gives me "undefined". (code below)

```
    slideChangedCallBack: function(idx, slide) {

        if (console) console.log('slideChangedCallBack: '+slide.data('pagename'));
        if (s && s.t){
            s.pageName = slide.data('pagename');
            s.t();
        }

        ...
    }
```

Comment: `window.location.hash` returns a string, such as `#2` in your case. Note the `#` character in the string compared to getting it from a data attribute where the `#` character isn't there.

Comment: I will now officially slap my face 2 times. Thank you for putting some sense in me Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

So, for anyone looking for exact change, I did this :-

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
```

instead of this:-

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

Comment: Would you accept this answer, by clicking the tick icon to the left? Thanks!